# Why is my redux reducer not setting the correct state?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to set the state in my redux reducer using the information that is passed in through the payload.
Am I trying to update the data state incorrectly?
Here is the reducer

```
const initialState = {
  data: {
    emailValid: true,
    passwordValid: true,
  },
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_REQUEST":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: {
          name: action.payload.name,
          email: action.payload.email,
          password: action.payload.password,
        },
      };
    case "LOGIN_EMAIL_FAILED":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: {
          emailValid: action.payload,
          passwordValid: true,
        },
      };
    case "LOGIN_PASSWORD_FAILED":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: {
          emailValid: true,
          passwordValid: action.payload,
        },
      };
    case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
        data: {},
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default loginReducer;
```

and here is the action

```
dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
          payload: response.data.user,
        });
```

This is a sample payload that I am passing in

```
{
        "address": [],
        "orders": [],
        "cardInfo": [],
        "savedForLater": [],
        "cart": [],
        "_id": "6111a57a1f39fb0015d243ba",
        "name": "Tim Taylor",
        "email": "timtay471@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$Zwa5zqZMO1Rm8bsWKJSP..FuxYY1ThDM8mPAPiW7lVtq0izYxIsv2",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

I have double checked that the response.data.user is an object that includes the keys 'name', 'email', 'password' inside of it with values assigned to them. I can log each of the values individually and it will contain the correct information. When I call the action it will work properly other than I do not get the state that is inside the data array. I am unsure if there is something incorrect with my logic? Can you not pass an object as the payload?

Comment: Please provide some more code snippets - like the initial state of the reducer and the way you are trying to access the information in the store later.

Comment: const name = useSelector((state) => state.loginReducer.data.name; this is how i am trying to access it but I am just getting undefined. Even if I change the payload to a string it still does not get passed to the reducer. I also added the initial state in the original post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-chatterjee-31e63?file=/src/App.js) of a minimal clone of the code you posted here.

I suspect the issue lies in connecting the store to the app in the index.js file, but i'm not sure since i haven't seen that part of your code.

Comment: I think I have found the issue, I was calling window.open("/home", "_self"); after my dispatch and for some reason that is prevent the state from updating. If i remove that the store updates correctly so I will have to figure out another way to redirect to that page

Comment: May i suggest using react-router-dom? It has a well written documentation and there are plenty of tutorials for it. If navigating to a different url while refreshing is required, try using window.location.href = 'https://your-address.com'